# Load multiple RData files efficiently

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-binding, rdata

I have a question that concerns reading files into R. I have a folder with many files that I would like to have in a dataframe in R to work with. What is the most efficient way to read in a large amount of data (over 1000 files)? My code is below, it has been running for a day now and still not all files are read in.

```
data = data.frame()
  
  for(file in files) {
    path = paste0("Data/",file,".RData") 
    if(file.exists(path)) {
      load(path) # as file_data
      data = dplyr::bind_rows(data, file_data)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can list all the files and read them into a list. Then bind them at the end.

```
my_files <- list.files(path = "Data/", pattern = "*.RData", full.names = T)

all_data <- lapply(my_files, load, .GlobalEnv)

bind_rows(mget(unlist(all_data)))
```

A better solution than using `mget` is defining a `new.env` to load the files there and then read them into a list:

```
my_files <- list.files(path = "Data/", pattern = "*.RData", full.names = T)

temp <- new.env()
lapply(my_files, load, temp)

all_data <- as.list(temp)
rm(temp) 

bind_rows(all_data)
```

Comment: For my understanding, why would this method be faster?

Comment: I'm still scratching my head at the plausibility of a `/`-less path, even with '.' default, though I guess getwd() would show us in some .Data/ directory, and full.names will disambiguate. The `<- lapply( , load)` was my stumbling block. Simply working might improve things prior to making faster.

Comment: @dlwhch This code is faster because it removes several operations from the loop: 1) `paste` is completely avoided; 2) only one `bind_rows` not 1000's, each of them calling the memory management routines; 3) no `if` condition to check, `list.files` already found all files matching the pattern.

Comment: @Chris I am not sure if I get what do you mean by *"Simply working might improve things prior to making faster."* Care to elaborate?

Comment: I have tried this approach now and I only get a list of the file names in all_data but I want the real dataframe behind it. Why?

Comment: @dlwhch see the edit, this should work now for `load`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `fs` to make a list of the files then use `map_dfr`. I use this for csv and excel files but I am presuming it should work the same with `load` for .Rdata files.

```
library(fs)
library(tidyverse)

file_list <- dir_ls("Data")
data <- file_list %>% 
  map_dfr(~ get(load(.)))
```

Comment: I like the idea of using `purrr` but why do we need to use `ft::dir_ls`? is it better than `base::list.files`?

Comment: @M-- that is an excellent question that I do not know enough currently to answer. Quite possible there is no difference and that's just what I found a while ago when trying to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Here's a start: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/vignettes/function-comparisons.html but performance needs to be compared further. By the way, do you mean `fs`? I cannot find a package called `ft`!

Comment: oh my goodness yes. I've been working on a project where I have ft_ at the start of a bunch of objects lol. I fixed it in the answer.

Comment: I tried `map_dfr` and it seems some adjustments is needed for it to work. Use this ```c1 <- data.frame(a = 1, b=1); c2 <- data.frame(a = 2, b=3); save(c1, file = "Data/a.Rdata"); save(c2, file = "Data/b.Rdata")``` as a reproducible example to check your solution. I took my +1 away till you fix it but if you get it right it deserves more than just one upvote. Cheers.

Comment: I got it thanks to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054275/loading-multiple-rdata-and-binding-into-a-single-data-frame). (I was close to getting there by myself though!) You use `get`, so it's `map_dfr(~ get(load(.)))`.

Comment: @M-- took me a while to get back to this but `fs` is needed for this to work. `list.files` only pulls the file name, not the entire file path. `dir_ls` pulls the entire file page which is needed for `purrr` to map over.

Comment: `list.files` has an argument called `full.names` which is set to `FALSE` by default but as I have used it in my answer, it can be set to `TRUE` to get the full path.

Comment: I thought that seemed like too easy of an answer. I mean since that's not an issue there is no functional difference. And since I doubt anyone will be reading in millions of files at once speed isn't a meaningful issue (I found `fs` was faster with increasing #s of files but like I said, it doesn't matter here). There are other `fs` functions that don't have base equivalents that I have used though.